# For and if in print python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to write this code in a row? How can I write it?

please help me

```
b=list(input().split())
a=[]
for c in b:
    if int(c)%6==0 and ((b.index(c))+1)%6==0:
        a.append(c)
print(*a)
```

Comment: `print(*[c for c in b if int(c)%6==0 and ((b.index(c))+1)%6==0])` But instead of trying to get everything on a single line, try to make your code more readable.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a row"? Do you mean on one line as a list comprehension? Why? It's perfectly fine as it is.

Comment: Note that `b.index(c)` will not do what you expect if there are duplicates in the list. It will return the index of the first copy, not the current index. Use `enumerate()` to get the actual index.

Answer (score 1):

As juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, make the code more clear instead of minimize it into one single line.

But challenge accepted:

```
print(*filter(lambda x: int(x)%6==0, input().split()[5::6]))
```